# multiple setTimeout to delay modification of CSS

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

I'm trying  to put in pratice closures and setTimeout after reading "multiple setTimeout calls within a for loop"  and "JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example".

In my html i have 10 div, everyone with his own class. The only difference is the backgroundColor. 
The CSS is linked in the html.

What i want to do is applying a delay before changing the color of a div : div1 / delay / div2/ delay..... So far, with the code below,  i can only have all div color changed in the same time after one and only one delay.

Thanks for helping,

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE 
 <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainCSS.css" title="compact" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var myVar;  // setTimeout
    var i=0; // index for css rules

var colorTab = ["red","blue","violet","black","yellow","green","DarkOrange","cyan","coral","silver"];
var colorTab = ["red","blue","violet","black","yellow","green","DarkOrange","cyan","coral","silver"];


function stop(){
clearTimeout(myVar);
}

function changeCSS(obj,numColor){
obj.style.backgroundColor=colorTab[numColor];
alert(numColor);
}

function getStyleSheet() {  
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    var j=0;// index for colorTab

    for(var i=0; i<sheet.cssRules.length-1;i++){
        obj=sheet.cssRules[i];

        (function(obj,j) {
            var myVar=setTimeout(function() {changeCSS(obj,j);},500);           
            })(obj,j);

        if (j==9){ 
            j=0;
        }else 
            {j=j+1;}
        }
}   


</script>
</head>
<body >
<p>
<button onclick="getStyleSheet()">GO</button><button onclick="stop()">STOP</button>
</p> 
<div class="animate1" ></div><div class="animate2" ></div><div class="animate3"></div><div class="animate4"></div>
<div class="animate5" ></div><div class="animate6"></div><div class="animate7"></div><div class="animate8"></div><div class="animate9"></div><div class="animate10">
</div>
</body>
      </html>
```

And the css :

```
<pre>
div.animate1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color: red;
}
div.animate2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color: blue;
}
div.animate3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color: violet;
}
div.animate4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color: black;
}
div.animate5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color:yellow;
}
div.animate6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color: green;
}
div.animate7 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color: DarkOrange;
}
div.animate8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color: cyan;
}
div.animate9 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color: coral;
}
div.animate10 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: ;
  background-color: silver;
}
<code>
```

Comment: You need to somehow make this chain not async. You can try to call setTimeout for second div inside function, that handles setTimeout for first div, and etc. Not good at all :) Also you can use Promises and make div1Handle.then(div2Handle).then...

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the same time for all the setTimeout.

```
var myVar=setTimeout(function() {changeCSS(obj,j);},500);
```

Your code should be :

```
var myVar=setTimeout(function() {changeCSS(obj,j);},500 * i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing. I've tried both proposed methods but didn't make it!
I finally used recursion and it does the job i wanted. Below is the code.
I will stil working on it. Thoose nested if - else are a kludge.

Js code :

```
        /* 
       This script changes the colors of the divs.The colors go up, the     color     of   one div is
    changed with the color of the div coming after the former. One loop is achieved when all the colors
    ve moved one div up. As there is 10 div in the html, 10 steps (0 to 9) are necessary for one loop.
    Second goal is to perform as much loop as necessary to have the colors get their initial position.
    This require 10 loops(0 to 9). */ 


    // index for loops
    var loop =0;    

    // index for css objects
    var i=0; 

    // index for steps   
    var step = 0; 

    // index for colorTab
    var j=1;

    // Get the styleSheet to work with
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];

    // Get the css rule to work with
    var obj=sheet.cssRules[0];


    /* thoose initial values realize the first step of the first loop */

    function changeCSS(){

                var colorTab = ["red","blue","violet","black","yellow","green","DarkOrange","cyan","coral","silver"];   

                // perform the changing of color
                obj.style.backgroundColor=colorTab[j];

                    // is a loop complete ?
                    if (step == 10){  

                        // are all the 10 loops completed ?
                        if( loop == 9){
                            // reset 
                            loop = 0;
                            j = 1;
                            i = 0;

                            // there are (is) stil loop(s) remaining
                            } else {
                                // next loop
                                loop += 1;

                                    if( loop == 9){
                                        j = 0;
                                        } else {
                                        j = loop +1;
                                        }
                                i = 0;

                            }
                    //  reset steps numbering as a new loop starts
                    step = 0 ;

                    // in a loop
                    } else {

                            // the last color of the tab is reached, so go on with 
                            // the first one
                            if (j == 9){
                                j = 0;

                                // if not go to the next color
                                }else {

                                j+=1;
                                }
                            // the last div is reached, continue with the first one
                            if (i == 9){
                                i = 0;

                                // if not, go to the next div
                                }else {
                                 i+= 1;
                                 }

                        // go to next step      
                        step += 1;              
                    }

                // Get positioned to the next div
                obj = sheet.cssRules[i];

                // Recursion on changeCSS with setTimeout   
                setTimeout(changeCSS,50);

    } // End of changeCSS

    function init() {
        'use strict';

        // Confirm that document.getElementById() can be used:
        if (document && document.getElementById) {
            var buttonGo = document.getElementById('go');
            buttonGo.onclick = changeCSS;
        }

    } // End of init() function.

    // Assign an event listener to the window's load event:
    window.onload = init;
```

And the html :

```
 <pre>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainCSS.css"     title="compact" />
     </head>

    <body>

    <p>
    <button id = "go" onclick="changeCSS()">GO</button>
    </p> 
    <div class="animate1" ></div><div class="animate2" ></div><div class="animate3"></div><div class="animate4"></div>
    <div class="animate5" ></div><div class="animate6"></div><div class="animate7"></div><div class="animate8"></div><div class="animate9">      </div><div class="animate10">
    </div>
    <script src="jsSetTimeout.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
</pre>
```